# Why is there two different commands for the same infinity symbol?

Tags: symbols

Here are the two different commands that lead to the same symbol:

- `\infty` = $\infty$
- `\infin` = $\infin$

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \infin` You have presumably loaded some code you have not shown that defines `\infin` (`\infty` is defined by latex)

Comment: always post a document which shows the issue,  eg `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\infty$
$\infin$
\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That makes sense; I'm using the Markdown preview in VS Code to render it. How come they are not rendered on this website by the way?

Comment: we do not use mathjax on this site (as it is about tex, not javascript implementations of math rendering)

Comment: TeX rendering is turned off here because it's the code that matters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- OK, I stand corrected. I meant rendering of (some) TeX syntax by something that isn't actually TeX.

Comment: texvc.sty? `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/texvc/texvc.sty:\newcommand{\infin}{\infty}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power of a complete example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\infin$
\end{document}
```

results in

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \infin 
                       
l.3 $\infin
           $
```

So the answer is "there are not, unless you define them".